# How to encode python variables into URL and web-server response?

Tags: python, xml, json, api, url

Assume that I have a Python function that takes several arguments as input and returns an output.

Now I would like to have a "web-service" (API) based on this function. It means that there should be a URL that can be called with some parameters, this parameters should be passed to the function, the function takes them and calculates a corresponding result (output) and passes it back to the web-server that, in its turn, shows the result to the user (probably another program).

In case of a simple function that takes two real-valued arguments (for example `x` and `y`) and returns one real-valued result, the call of the function can be organized throw get parameters. For example:

```
www.my_web_site.org/my_func_name?x=1.234&y=3.456
```

As a result I expect a web-page containing only one real number.

However, it is not so obvious to me what should I do with a more complex input. Assume that as values of some arguments we can have list and dictionaries. How should I encode them in the URL. I can imagine something like that:

```
www.my_web_site.org/my_func_name?x=[1,2,3,4]&y={1:'a',2:'b'}
```

However, I am not sure that this is an elegant solution. Are there any standards how to do it? Maybe I should use XML or JSON to encode the input.

The same question is applicable to the output. Assume that we can have dictionary or list or even a set as output. How should I represent it. Should I just use `str(output)` or there is another "standard" solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I just use `str(output)`?

No! First of all, you'd want the `repr()` since it returns valid Python code for many builtin Python types. However, to parse the output of that, you'd need to execute it somehow. And while Python has [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) which is safe to run on untrusted input (it only handles strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and `None`), it's still not very portable and somewhat ugly to pass around Python code for data.

---

The best solution is to encode it using [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). You can do so using `json.dumps` to serialize and `json.loads` to deserialize.

- It can be parsed in pretty much every single language, so even if you want to send a request from another tool you can easily create the parameter
- It is a standardized format and easily readable by humans, too.
- It is safe to unserialize untrusted data (you can't write JSON that becomes a massive memory hog when unserializing and you can't execute arbitrary code like you could with [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html))
- It does not add massive bloat/overheard like XML would do.

However, I would use POST instead of GET when sending JSON payloads (even though it's safe to url-encode JSON data - but having a long string of JSON in a URL is not that pretty). That way you can simply dump the whole JSON structure in the request body, use an `application/json` Content-type and in your backend you might even be able to access it easily, e.g. [`request.get_json()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.get_json) if you are using Flask.

If you need to support variable types which are not [natively supported](http://json.org/value.gif) in JSON you can simply subclass the JSON encoder/decoder and convert such types to whatever notation you like, e.g. an ISO date string for datetime objects.

Answer (score 0):

### RESTful style

```
GET /rectangle/1.34553/7.3439
GET /rectangle?x=1.5478;y=7.4535
```

### Hacks

```
GET /rectangle?args=%5B1.5467%2C+7.543%5D  # urlencoded json
GET /rectangle?_=WzEuNTY3NCwgNy4zNTQ2Mjdd  # url-safe base64 encoded json
GET /rectangle?_=eJzTyCkw4PI05EocxYMH6wEAXqha4Q  # left as exercise for the reader
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar scenario (a database intermediator). We started with GET but then switched over to POST to provide the inputs as there are different limits on URL lengths in different browsers. urlencoding of parameters was also expensive and hard to eyeball.

Our preferred way of sending input was JSON, but with a few conventions. JSON is easy to read when compared to XML, and can easily provide parameters to a Python function via **kwargs method. But there is a dependence on the caller knowing the names of the arguments. This is harder than you might imagine, as it makes any change in name (e.g., a typo in an parameter name) hard to fix and introduces a level of brittleness. (No obvious solution comes to my mind for that!) A separate list provides the positional sequencing of parameters. This mattered for us because the other end of the web service was a DB PROC and the SQL is still stuck in the last millennia with strictly positional parameters. With pure Python server side, this might not be an issue for you, but think also of C++, etc.

On the output side we alternate between straight JSON and a variant of CSV because we did not want to incur the costs of processing a huge number of rows as JSON hash objects. So we also use arrays of CSV strings (1 row=1 string) to encode rows, have a header row object, and parse it back into an array of row objects at the receiving end.

HTH. I doubt if there is a "right" answer.